# error when page is refreshed in django

Tags: python, django, html

I am learning to create a website using django. I have a homepage through which user can select city. The next page shows the list of hotels.It works properly,but when page is refreshed it gives me error

This is my html file for list page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-backstretch/2.0.4/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="../js/typeahead/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

{% load static %}
<script src="/static/typeahead.js "></script>



</head>
<body>

<div >
<div style="float:left; background-color:#d9d9d9;margin-top:100px;width:30%;height:800px;">
<h2 style="text-align:center;">Filters</h2>
<div  style="width:95%; margin-left: 10px; " >
    <form method="post" data-ajax="false" action="{% url 'list' %}">
     {% csrf_token %}

       <div data-role="rangeslider" data-mini="true" style="width:100%">
    <label for="range-1a">price:</label>
    <input name="range-1a" id="range-1a" min="0" max="100" value="0" type="range">
    <label for="range-1b">Rangeslider:</label>
    <input name="range-1b" id="range-1b" min="0" max="100" value="100" type="range">
  </div>
  <input type="submit"  value="Submit">
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div style=" float:right;margin-right:30px;margin-top:100px;width:60%;height:80%">



{% for hotel in city_list %}
{% load static %}

   <div class="col-md-4" style="width:45%;border:0;position:relative;">
    <div class="thumbnail" style="height:300px; background-color:black;border:0;border-radius:0;position:relative;box-shadow:0;" >
      <a href="/w3images/lights.jpg" data-ajax="false">
        <img src="{% static hotel.photo.url %}" style="border:0;height:85%;width:100%;"  >
        <div class="caption">
          <p style="color:white;">Name</p>
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>






{% endfor %}

</div>  


</div>



</body>
</html>
```

This is my views.py

```
def homepage(request):
    hotel_list=Hotels.objects.all()
    context={'hotel_list':hotel_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/homepage.html',context)

def wholelist(request):
    hotelvar=request.POST.get('service_type')
    if hotelvar=='Hotels':

      city_list=Hotels.objects.filter(city_name__iexact=request.POST.get('searchabc'))
    if not city_list:
        hotel_list=Hotels.objects.all()
        context={'hotel_list':hotel_list}
        return render(request, 'polls/homepage.html',context)

    pricemin=200
    pricemax=800

    context={'pmin':pricemin,'pmax':pricemax,'city_list':city_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/list.html',context)
```

i get the following error when refreshed
`UnboundLocalError` at /polls/wholelist/
local variable `city_list` referenced before assignment

`city_list` is being passed from the homepage, but when page is reloaded it not being passed. Is there a way to pass it when page is refreshed?

Comment: Should i use session variables to retain the values?

Comment: You didn't need to post that whole template including the CSS; cut it down to the minimum necessary to demonstrate what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

when `hotelvar` not equal to 'Hotels', variable `city_list` is not set

```
def wholelist(request):
    hotelvar=request.POST.get('service_type')
    city_list = None
    if hotelvar=='Hotels':
          city_list=Hotels.objects.filter(city_name__iexact=request.POST.get('searchabc'))
    if not city_list:
        hotel_list=Hotels.objects.all()
        context={'hotel_list':hotel_list}
        return render(request, 'polls/homepage.html',context)

    pricemin=200
    pricemax=800
    context={'pmin':pricemin,'pmax':pricemax,'city_list':city_list}
    return render(request, 'polls/list.html',context)
```

Comment: i removed that if condition.The value of city_list is getting reset. So "if not city_list"condition is getting true. I post data is lost

Comment: @ShubhamYelekar If you need to retain the search parameters when the city lists are none then instead of refreshing the page by rendering the page, just send a json response for the Ajax request. Or you can pass in the POST values as context to the homepage through the render  method and work with it in the template

Comment: "Or you can pass in the POST values as context to the homepage through the render method and work with it in the template" can you please explain it